# AdMob - An blank space when the admob banner is not loaded

Tags: android, view, admob, space

Since I migrated to Google play services in my application for the banner advertising, it takes up blank space all the time even when no ad is loaded.

I do not want the banner to take blank space when it is not loaded.

My XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/icon_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:numColumns="4" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-ABC/ABC" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Hide the visibility of the your adView to `android:visibility="gone"` as

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-ABC/ABC"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

and handle adview visibility in `setAdListener` as

```
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int error) {
        adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLeftApplication() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdOpened() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hide the visibility of the your add to GONE, and make it visible once its loaded.

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-ABC/ABC"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

And when you want to make it visible, that is, just before loading the ad :

```
adviewName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```